# Wrong bone placement on object and pose mode during the eyes rigging

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones

I'm trying to learn how to rig eyes and I realized that while I'm on edit mode,the bones are placed correctly,but if I switch under object and pose mode,they aren't. Why ? How can I fix that ? I attached 3 pictures to show you...

[image: bones in edit mode]

[image: bones in pose mode]

[image: bones in object mode]

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a scaled *Parent* bone.

Like objects, each bone may have a parent bone that it follows by default. This parent is indicated in the `Relations` panel of the `Bone Properties`:

[image]

As noted in the properties, the default behavior for *Child* bones is to inherit the Rotation and Scale of the parent. The effect of this, as you've seen, is for some bones to seemingly move in `Pose Mode` from their original location in `Edit Mode`.

To fix this simply select all bones in Pose Mode and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to reset their scale and rotation.

You can easily find the parent of any bone, if there is one, by selecting a bone in Edit Mode and then `Select > Parent`:

[image: Select parent of active bone]

Anytime you extrude a bone the newly extruded bone is automatically parented, and connected to the bone it was extruded from.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I did it,but the bones in pose mode are still placed in the wrong way. Check this picture : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-25_19-07-20.png

Comment: Could you upload the .blend?

Comment: sure : get it here : http://psychonews.it/dati/Pierino87.blend

Comment: Ah ha, the issue is all the Track To constraints.

Comment: :) what should I do to fix the issue ?

Comment: Depends on your end goal. As it is right now the constraints are doing their job, tracking the tail of the bone to the Eye controller. The head (root) of the bone is not actually moving, so the bone location is not changing, just the rotation.

Comment: Hello man. I removed all the "track to constraints" and I selected all bones in Pose Mode and I pressed ALT+R and ALT+S to reset their scale and rotation,but it didn't work again. Check these pictures : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-26_16-53-22.png and http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-26_16-53-40.png ; pressing ALT + R and ALT + S did nothing.